# Permissions inside docker

Tags: docker, vagrant

I have tried to switch my local development procedures and start working by using the vagrant machine and dockers. I have build up a virtual machine and created a docker, however I get an error every time that I am trying to run my symfony 1.4 application in the browser. The message says that I don't have the right permissions for a specific file related to symfony.

```
Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted 
in/usr/local/lib/symfony/symfony1.4.20/lib/config/sfConfigCache.class.php     
on line 365 Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine_Template_WebEntity' not 
found in/shore_site/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseProductGroup.class.php 
on line 286
```

I have tried to change the permissions of this file both inside the vagrant machine and the docker to 777. I have changed the ownership of the file to www-data:www-data but still no luck.
The initial permissions were 644 and the ownership root:root.

Are there any ideas what I have to do for this one?

Comment: Can you provide the steps to create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, including any Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, out input files, and commands you've run?